# Where should a Windows application's working files be written?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file

If you have a Windows application that needs to write working files as part of its normal operation (not prompted by the user):

- Where on the file system should they be written?
- What's the correct way to get this directory in .NET for all Windows versions (XP/V/7/Server)?

(Writing to the same directory as the executable or a "temp" directory are not suitable for my specific case.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common place would be:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(
      Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

But there are other values of Environment.SpecialFolder that could be useful. And of course there is the User's `Documents` folder.

And you say you don't want a Temp file but if you need it in 1 session,

```
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
```

can be very useful.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0.aspx) ([Intro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx).)  It may be used per assembly, per machine, per user, and any combination of above.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked and answered before on Stackoverflow. Check the following two questions:

[My winform app uses xml files to store data, where should I store them so Vista users can write to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588207/my-winform-app-uses-xml-files-to-store-data-where-should-i-store-them-so-vista-u)

[Windows Standard File Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615444/windows-standard-file-locations)

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` would be the .NET way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, under AppData (usually %APPDATA%\[company name]\[application name] -- the location of %APPDATA% is different between XP and Vista/7, so be sure to use an abstraction layer and don't hardcode the path) is the standard location.  Please, please, please, please don't put them anywhere under Program Files.